# axios post file in vuejs return null

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js, multipartform-data

I've been trying to post a file with axios to my database.

```html
<template>
<div>
 <v-file-input
                v-model="file"
                label="File input"
                id="file"
                ref="file"
        >
</v-file-input>
  <button v-on:click="submitFile()">Submit</button>
</div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  name: "Test",
  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitFile() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', this.file);
      axios.post('https://test_file_create/', formData).then(function() {
        console.log('SUCCESS!!');
      }).catch(function() {
        console.log('FAILURE!!');
      });
    },

  },
}
```

but the problem is in my database i got my file column null it seems it can't post the file although it return "SUCCESS!!" in submitFile function.
can someone please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you storing an `actual` file in the database ?

Comment: i have deleted the headers too but the problem is still there and i don't have any error in my console

Comment: What does your server-side look like? How exactly are you verifying that the file has not been uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

You've made a couple of mistakes here so from most severe to least...

1. The [`<v-file-input>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs/) component binds the selected file to its model but you are using the `handleFileUpload()` method to set your `file` property to the component itself (via `$refs`).

   Try this instead, using `v-model` with your `file` property initialised to `null` instead of an empty string (which doesn't make sense for a `File` object)

   ```html
   <v-file-input
     v-model="file"
     label="File input" 
     id="file" 
     ref="file"
   ></v-file-input>
   ```

   ```js
   export default {
     name: "Test",
     data: () => ({ file: null }),
     // etc
   }
   ```
2. When sending a `FormData` instance from the browser, do not manually add the `content-type` header. `FormData` also requires special mime-boundary tokens which should be handled automatically

   ```js
   axios.post("https://test_file_create/", formData).then(res => ...)
   ```
3. You should only have [one root element](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#A-Single-Root-Element) in your template. `<div>` is a popular choice

   ```html
   <template>
     <div>
       <v-file-input
         v-model="file"
         label="File input" 
         id="file" 
         ref="file"
       ></v-file-input>     
       <button :disabled="!file" type="button" @click="submitFile">Submit</button>
     </div>
   </template>
   ```

Comment: with using  <v-file-input> i can not assign a v-model i get an error so i had to use handleFileUpload() insted and i have seen others had the same problem with v-model too. i have change my code to  axios.post("https://test_file_create/", formData).then(res => ...) but still it doesn't work

Comment: when i use v-model i get an error Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "value"

Comment: @t.khatibi I've updated my answer. It's because you set `file` to be an empty string by default

Comment: i have updated my code too due to your changes but in my json file when i post an .xlsx file i get it like :  [{"pk":11,"attachment":null}]

Comment: @t.khatibi at this stage, it must be a problem with your server-side code